# How to ignore EMPTY/NULL value columns while grouping in python polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a dataframe.

```
df_X = pl.DataFrame({'last_name':['James','Warner','Marino','James','Warner','Marino','James'],
             'first_name':['Horn','Bro','Kach','Horn','Bro','Kach','Horn'],
             'dob':['03/06/1990','09/16/1990','03/06/1990','','03/06/1990','','']}
            )
```

[image]

I'm applying a grouping on last,first and dob columns to get the counts as

```
df_X.groupby(['last_name','first_name','dob']).agg(pl.count())
```

[image]

Here i would like to ignore the NULL/EMPTY values on grouping columns as

James Horn has two empty DOB's these should not be included to grouping operation.

Here is the expected output.

[image]

Of course we can do filter on the column as below before pass to grouping as

```
df_X.filter(pl.col('dob')!="").groupby(['last_name','first_name','dob']).agg(pl.count())
```

But what if I have 10 columns to be specified in filter operation ? i need to write them one after another.

Is there any other solution for it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First replace empty strings with `null` values and then use drop_nulls

```py
(
    df_X
    .with_columns(
        [
            pl.when(pl.col(group_columns).str.lengths() ==0)
            .then(None)
            .otherwise(pl.col(group_columns))
            .keep_name()
        ]
    )
    .drop_nulls(group_columns)
    .groupby(group_columns)
    .count()
)
shape: (4, 4)
┌───────────┬────────────┬────────────┬───────┐
│ last_name ┆ first_name ┆ dob        ┆ count │
│ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ str       ┆ str        ┆ str        ┆ u32   │
╞═══════════╪════════════╪════════════╪═══════╡
│ Warner    ┆ Bro        ┆ 09/16/1990 ┆ 1     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Marino    ┆ Kach       ┆ 03/06/1990 ┆ 1     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Warner    ┆ Bro        ┆ 03/06/1990 ┆ 1     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ James     ┆ Horn       ┆ 03/06/1990 ┆ 1     │
└───────────┴────────────┴────────────┴───────┘
```